# SetNeedsDisplayInRect not taking effect immediately

Tags: iphone, mapkit

When I call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`, why isn't my `drawRect:inContext` method being called soon after? If I zoom into the unpainted area, then zoom out (I guess triggering a repaint) the image will be drawn. But if I leave it sitting there, no dice. Is there a way to force a repaint immediately?

Just in case it matters, I'm really using MapKit's overlays and the `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:zoomScale:` and `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` methods, but I had this problem previously with just a scrollview and a CATiledLayer.

Comment: Will - did you ever solve this?  I have a very similar problem, which I've posted about here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128447/setneedsdisplayinmaprect-doesnt-trigger-new-drawmaprect-call

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you be using

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
        zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
        inContext:(CGContextRef)context

not drawRect:inContext:

Comment: I am using that method (second paragraph). It seems to be working better now for some reason, but I still get some tiles that won't draw even if they're supposed to (by invalidating them with `setNeedsDisplayIn`…).