# MKTileOverlay: How to reload a specific tile or region

Tags: ios, mapkit, mktileoverlay

I'm working on a map-based app. I used a `MKTileOverlay` to show some dynamic contents. Occasionally certain tiles need reloading when new information arrives.

I've tried to call `overlayRenderer.setNeedsDisplayInMapRect(mapRect)` in main thread but apparently it doesn't trigger a map redraw in my case. So far the only approach that works is `overlayRenderer.reloadData()`. However, this will cause the entire contents (instead of only specific region) to be reloaded and lead to flickering in the view, so this is not a option for me.

Can anyone give any advice on this? Thanks & Cheers.

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128447/setneedsdisplayinmaprect-doesnt-trigger-new-drawmaprect-call

Comment: Thanks but yeah I tried the approaches mentioned in this post. None of them works for me. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. In fact, the overlay's not updating is not due to `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect`. After several checks I found that `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect` is actually causing a run of `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:`, however, somehow a default redraw produces the same tile image. I guess this may due to some internal cache of MKTileOverlayRender.

The solution for me is to subclass the `MKTileOverlayRender`, and in the new class:

```
override func canDrawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale) -> Bool {

    let tilePath = self.tilePathForMapRect(mapRect, andZoomScale: zoomScale)
    let tilePathString = stringForTilePath(tilePath)
    if let _ = self.cache.objectForKey(tilePathString) {
        return true
    } else {
        let tileOverlay = self.overlay as! MKTileOverlay
        tileOverlay.loadTileAtPath(tilePath, result: {
            data, error in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    self.cache.setObject(image, forKey: tilePathString)
                    self.setNeedsDisplayInMapRect(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale)
                }
            }
        })

        return false
    }
}

override func drawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, inContext context: CGContext) {
    let tilePath = self.tilePathForMapRect(mapRect, andZoomScale: zoomScale)
    let tilePathString = stringForTilePath(tilePath)

    if let image = self.cache.objectForKey(tilePathString) as? UIImage {
        CGContextDrawImage(context, self.rectForMapRect(mapRect), image.CGImage)
    } else {
        super.setNeedsDisplayInMapRect(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale)
    }

    self.cache.removeObjectForKey(tilePathString)
}
```